# How to focus a text box on pressing a key without entering that keyword into it

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I want to focus into a text box when ever be user press 'S' keyword in keyboard. But the problem is that 'S' keyword also typed in text box (this only happens in chrome). How I can do this here is my code.

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
if(document.getElementById('search')!==null)
{
    if(event.which==115 && event.target.nodeName=='BODY')   // WHEN USER PRESS 'S' KEYWORD IN KEYBOARD ONLY
    {
        $('#search').focus();           
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.preventDefault()`

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){

    if($('#search').length)
    {
        console.log(1);
        if(event.which==115 && event.target.nodeName=='BODY')   // WHEN USER PRESS 'S' KEYWORD IN KEYBOARD ONLY
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#search').focus();       
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: event.preventDefault() how I can miss this thank you, it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

```
(event.keyCode==83) // 83 is keyCode for "s"
```

Comment: `"s".charCodeAt(0) == 115`, `"S".charCodeAt(0) == 83`

Answer (score 0):

By using the **event.preventDefault()** you can restrict the keypress to update the textbox value. i have added **event.which == 83** in case of caps is on.

```
 $(document).keypress(function (event) {
        if (document.getElementById('search') !== null) {

            if ((event.which == 115 || event.which == 83) && event.target.nodeName == 'BODY')   // WHEN USER PRESS 'S' KEYWORD IN KEYBOARD ONLY
            {
                $('#search').focus();
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
```

Check the Demo for [JSFiddler DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bd3sy9gy/)